# mount Command Works, but fstab Version Fails - Samba Issue

Tags: network-shares, mount, samba, nfs, fstab

I can mount a share with this command:

`sudo mount -o username=user,password=pass //192.168.5.227/share /mnt/share`

And in my `fstab` I have this line:

`//192.168.5.227/share /mnt/share cifs credentials=/path/to/credentials 0 0`

and `mount -a` won't mount it.  I have tried this with `samba` installed but currently it isn't.  Same error:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //192.168.5.227/share
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
(for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might
need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail  or so
```

I have also tried with `nfs` to no avail.

My question is, if I can't get it working with `samba` is there a way to do it in `fstab` without a `<type>` like `cifs`?

Any help is appreciated, either in the direction of fixing the `samba` issue or not using it and mounting via `fstab` without it.

EDIT - So although strangeman didn't give me the exact answer I was looking for, I am more than happy because the `fstab` is actually working now.  But why doesn't the `credentials=/path/to/credential_file` work?  Is there something weird with this option in `fstab` that I don't know about?  I guess I could ask a new question too.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add "-o username=user,password=pass"

```
//192.168.xxx.xxx/dir  /mnt/dir  cifs  noauto,noperm,guest,iocharset=utf8  0   0
```

or

```
//192.168.xxx.xxx/dir  /mnt/dir  cifs  noauto,noperm,username=user,password=pass,iocharset=utf8  0   0
```

Comment: That's already in my credentials file (see above).  Plus, I also tried that and it gave the same error.

Comment: Hm... What say "dmesg | tail"?

Comment: `[178319.972284] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -13`

Comment: So your method worked.  Not sure why it didn't before, but after some restarts and rewriting lines, it's working.  Thanks.  Now to get the credentials file to work ;--)